# React Native Screen white blinking when moving between tabs

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

im working on a App and im Using a BottomTabBar and in there are StackNavigators. When i switch the screens the screens gets white, it seems like they are loading. but i just want it without a loading animation or transition. i just want it like whatsapp or instagram so i can swap between my screens but i need a header for my application.

```html
import React from "react";
import News from "../screens/News";
import Favorites from "../screens/Favorites";
import NewRecipe from "../screens/NewRecipe";
import Ingredients from "../screens/Ingredients";
import Profile from "../screens/Profile";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs";
import { MaterialIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";

export default function AppScreen() {
  const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();
  const NewsStack = createStackNavigator();
  const FavoritesStack = createStackNavigator();
  const NewRecipeStack = createStackNavigator();
  const IngredientsStack = createStackNavigator();
  const ProfileStack = createStackNavigator();

  function NewsNav() {
    return (
      <NewsStack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          animationEnabled: false,
        }}
      >
        <NewsStack.Screen
          name="News"
          component={News}
          options={{
            headerTintColor: "#277093",
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: "#272727",
              height: 75,
            },
            headerTitleStyle: {
              marginTop: -15,
            },
            animationEnabled: false,
          }}
        />
      </NewsStack.Navigator>
    );
  }

  function FavoritesNav() {
    return (
      <FavoritesStack.Navigator>
        <FavoritesStack.Screen
          name="Favoriten"
          component={Favorites}
          options={{
            headerTintColor: "#277093",
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: "#272727",
              height: 75,
            },
            headerTitleStyle: {
              marginTop: -15,
            },
          }}
        />
      </FavoritesStack.Navigator>
    );
  }

  function NewRecipeNav() {
    return (
      <NewRecipeStack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          cardStyle: {
            opacity: 1,
          },
        }}
      >
        <NewRecipeStack.Screen
          name="Neue Rezepte"
          component={NewRecipe}
          options={{
            headerTintColor: "#277093",
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: "#272727",
              height: 75,
            },
            headerTitleStyle: {
              marginTop: -15,
            },
          }}
        />
      </NewRecipeStack.Navigator>
    );
  }

  function IngredientsNav() {
    return (
      <IngredientsStack.Navigator>
        <IngredientsStack.Screen
          name="Zutaten"
          component={Ingredients}
          options={{
            headerTintColor: "#277093",
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: "#272727",
              height: 75,
            },
            headerTitleStyle: {
              marginTop: -15,
            },
          }}
        />
      </IngredientsStack.Navigator>
    );
  }

  function ProfileNav() {
    return (
      <ProfileStack.Navigator>
        <ProfileStack.Screen
          name="Profil"
          component={Profile}
          options={{
            headerTintColor: "#277093",
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: "#272727",
              height: 75,
            },
            headerTitleStyle: {
              marginTop: -15,
            },
          }}
        />
      </ProfileStack.Navigator>
    );
  }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
          tabBarIcon: ({}) => {
            let iconName;

            if (route.name == "News") {
              iconName = "language";
            } else if (route.name == "Favoriten") {
              iconName = "star-border";
            } else if (route.name == "Hinzufügen") {
              iconName = "add-circle-outline";
            } else if (route.name == "Zutaten") {
              iconName = "shopping-cart";
            } else if (route.name == "Profil") {
              iconName = "person";
            }
            return (
              <MaterialIcons
                name={iconName}
                color={"#277093"}
                size={25}
              ></MaterialIcons>
            );
          },
        })}
        tabBarOptions={{
          activeTintColor: "green",
        }}
        barStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#272727" }}
      >
        <Tab.Screen
          name="News"
          component={NewsNav}
          options={{ animationEnabled: false }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen name="Favoriten" component={FavoritesNav} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Hinzufügen" component={NewRecipeNav} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Zutaten" component={IngredientsNav} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Profil" component={ProfileNav} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

nsition but i cant fix it

Comment: I fixed it with sceneAnimationEnabled = {false} but now the header title are bugging and arent fixed

Answer (score 0):

Lower react-native-screen package version to 2.18.1 . Solution was obtained from this discussion.

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/9593

Other solutions like setting the theme in Navigation Container, setting the cardInterpolatorStyle, and other modifications to the screen options of the navigator did not work.

This issue was visible only on Android in my case.